# Increase the font size in one of the help center page's bottom line

Tags: feature-request, design, help-center

In the bottom of the ["How do I report harassment?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/harassment) help center page, the line's font size is very less and it is hard to read.

Can be the font size is increased in that line?

> [image: Font size issue]

Comment: It says: *Thanks to Twitter and Reddit, whose articles on harassment were helpful in creating some of the phrasing on this one.* Not much information that are worth showing in big letters for most readers.

Comment: If you find it hard to read, zoom in...

Answer (score 3):

This isn't just "one line", this is a credits section, which should have smaller font size.

I do agree they went too far though, and the size is too small. But it shouldn't be made the same size as the rest of the help center contents, maybe same size as the "site design / logo" part of the footer.